# "Which Allow me" or "Which Allows me"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, verbs

Context: "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events which allow me to learn ..."

Do I use "allows" or "allow"? Can you provide me the rules/situations in choosing which one to use for future reference? Thanks.

Comment: The verb *allow* associates with *be* here (*be(ing) at different areas* --> *allows me to learn*) or it can even be argued that *allow* refers back to *requires* (... *me to be*). Only the singular fits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one is correct, but the meaning changes. If the verb is plural, the *which* refers to the events. The events allow me to learn:

- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events which allow me to learn ..."

Another way to say this:

- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events, and these events allow me to learn ..."

If the verb is singular, the *which* refers to the entire prior clause as a situation: the situation of being required to be in different areas is what allows me to learn. In writing, we should use a comma in that case, by the way:

- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events, which allows me to learn ..."

Other ways to express this:

- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events, *and {this/that}* allows me to learn ..."
- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events, *which is what* allows me to learn ..."
- "My work requires me to be at different areas for different events, *and that {situation, arrangement, ...}* allows me to learn ..."

The entire clause is treated as kind of noun which can be referred to by words like *which* or *this* or *that*.

Sentences in which the plurality of the verb does not resolve the references are ambiguous: "I earn decent money, which allows me to live well". Here *which* could refer to money, or to the entire clause about earning. Whether or not a comma is written influences the interpretation of the written form, and there are ways to say it to emphasize one meaning versus the other.