# "A feature was created which allow(s)..."

Tags: word-choice

> As a result, a feature was created which **allow** the two devices to dynamically determine and switch their transmission wires.

Should I use *allow* or *allows* in this sentence?

PS: I have read [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114714/122271) a dozen times now and I still can't infer which is the correct form of *allow*.

Comment: ***A*** *feature* is singular. Thus *allows*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the verb *allow* refers to the noun *feature*. Since *feature* is singular, the verb should take the singular form *allows*.